# Unable to get all network interfaces with NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces on Linux

Tags: java, linux, networking

I need to print all the mac addresses of my machine. The recommended way is to use NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() and iterate on the enumeration returned. However when some devices are down ( NO Ip is configured ) then the above method will not return the interfaces.

#### Running "ip addr" will return the following

1. lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2. G2:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:03:b2:75:99:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3. G1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
   link/ether ***00:03:b2:75:99:c3*** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 10.205.191.123/16 brd 10.205.255.255 scope global G1
   inet6 fe80::203:b2ff:fe75:99c3/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4. eth2:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:03:b2:75:99:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5. eth3:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:03:b2:75:99:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

#### However when I run Java code (even as root or with network privileges) I only get the loopback and G1 interfaces.

Here is the code I wrote for testing purposes :

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(ni.hasMoreElements()){
NetworkInterface nextElement = ni.nextElement();
byte[] mac = nextElement.getHardwareAddress();
if (mac != null) {
         StringBuffer macAddress = new StringBuffer();
         for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
              macAddress.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? ":" : ""));
         }
         System.out.println(macAddress.toString());
}
}
```

The output is: ***00:03:B2:75:99:C3*** (of G1) only.

I do want a pure java solution if possible.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Found an openjdk bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "ip addr" shows all network adapters, but not all are configured with an internet address. So, the Java returns only network interfaces, i.e. configured adapters.

Comment: That's exactly my point. Java should return all adapters whether they are configured or not and let the developer decide how to continue with that. I think the Java doc is wrong on this one : **Returns all the interfaces on this machine. Returns null if no network interfaces could be found on this machine.** **NOTE**: can use getNetworkInterfaces()+getInetAddresses() to obtain all IP addresses for this node

Comment: There is a network card/adapter (a hardware device), there is a network interface (logical connection via a network card). Moreover, you can assign several interfaces via one card. So, the javadoc is correct, it returns interfaces. I suspect there is no easy way to list all cards with java, probably you have to use some native stuff.