# See what actually happens in NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

Tags: java, networking

I want to know what code actually executing behind NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); How can i find out it ? Where can i see native method ?

I need it, because suddenly this method start to take too long time (10 sec for only 3 network interfaces)

Comment: And what are you going to do once you find out the native implementation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698971/networkinterface-getnetworkinterfaces-not-listing-all-interfaces has some background - in case you are on linux (http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/windows/native/java/net/NetworkInterface.c#848 is the windows source)

Comment: thanks, zapl for sources, i found out that GetIFTable windows API function hangs